# Need help! no tails DVD boot up incomplete, something wrong?

Tags: tails

im user of no-tails for a while. i downloaded the latest version of iso 2.0.1 - 13 Feb 2016,

checked the SHA256 sum, its match. then burn it on blank DVD.

i restart computer and press hotkey so it boots up from the DVD, the loading works as usual, however once i reached the main blue login screen, i clicked login and it will bring me back to the login page again, this login process stucked in loop and im unable to load the operating sys properly.

Ive use the previous version of no-tails, its all fine and able to load the OS properly. except this version, its having problem. I tried burned another 5-6 copy of blank DVD its all having the same result

someone please tell me whats wrong?

Comment: What is "no tails"? Do you have a link? Do you mean "Tails"?